# Start cygwin bash.exe without inheriting windows home

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, ssh, cygwin

I want to be able to run in the cygwin environment from CMD but when I run `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l -i` my home gets set to the windows home. As I understand bash.exe inherits the environment from the CMD that run it and I don't want that. When I run the desktop icon with the shortcut to `C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -` I get the correct home `/home/MY_USERNAME` unlike with bash.exe with which I get `/cygdrive/c/Users/MY_USERNAME`.

What can I do to make bash.exe open with the same environment as mintty.exe? I need this to  work in cygwin over ssh.

Comment: If you have the user environment variable HOME set in `System Properties` -> `Advanced` -> `Environment Variables`  -> `User variables`, then cygwin will start in the specified directory in cases where it would normally start in /home/MY_USERNAME.  _Just happened to me, doh_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running CygWin commands like `bash` or `rsync` directly can work but it doesn't have to. It's not intended to do this.

If you want to start CygWin in a clean way you have to run `Cygwin.bat`. The default locations are:

```
C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat
C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat
```

I personally use the `.bash_profile` file to start a bash script when `Cygwin.bat` is executed.

This file has to be in your CygWin home directory. Run `Cygwin.bat` once so it will create your home directory and some default files automatically.

```
C:\cygwin\home\username
C:\cygwin64\home\username
```

Replace `username`.

Add this to `.bash_profile` at the end:

```
if [[ -v MY_BASH_SCRIPT ]]; then
  source "$MY_BASH_SCRIPT"
fi
```

Now you can pass a path to a bash script by setting the environment variable `MY_BASH_SCRIPT` before executing `Cygwin.bat`.

In the Windows command line you do it like this:

```
set MY_BASH_SCRIPT=/cygdrive/C/...
```

In PowerShell you do it like this:

```
$Env:MY_BASH_SCRIPT = "/cygdrive/C/..."
```

Once set up it's very easy to use. Simply set the `MY_BASH_SCRIPT` environment variable and then run `Cygwin.bat`. This is possible from a batch file but also from PowerShell.